# Why JFormattedTextField does not suppport actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` in my form, and i wish that after entering value when user presses enters it should move to next field. But after my all tries I am failed to do so.
To achieve this I have attached an `ActionListener` to `JFormattedTextField` but pressing of Enter never trigger event. Why? can anybody help?

```
public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Test
     */
    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        ftf = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ftf.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#0.00"))));
        ftf.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ftfActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("JFormattedTextField Action Test");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(ftf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 195, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(167, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(ftf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(238, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void ftfActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Enter Pressed");
    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField ftf;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"when user presses enters it should move to next field"* - Why? [Enter] is not a navigation key the user would expect

Comment: The `ActionListener` is not be triggered, because you're input is invalid, try entering "0.0" into the field and pressing [Enter]

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're absolutely right [Enter] is not a navigation key, but in India all accounting software employ this mechanism i.e. when you  are in a form then pressing [Enter] validates field and moves to next field and people here are used to do so, and my project is also a type of accounting software. That's why...

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're referring me "OP", what does it mean?

Comment: "Original Poster"

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tested and found that when input is valid `ActionListener` invoked, but when input is valid but not changed i.e. no modification, then `ActionListener` is not invoked. In that case focus does not move to next field. Can you tell me how to move to next field in that case.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) to see you can work with and modify the focus sub system, which would be a better and more reliable solution then to change the way that the system works, then setting focus listeners and actions on all your controls and other hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `Action`:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //preform your action here.
    }
};


ftf.addActionListener( action );
```

And the action is executed when enter key is pressed.

Comment: No, no a thousand times no - you NEVER add a `KeyListener` to a text component, you can use a `DocumentListener` to monitor for changes to the field or a `DocumentFilter` to filter what is commited to the document but never use a `KeyListener`

Comment: @MadProgrammer aw sh**. I forgot. (Been a while since I've used swing and not FX, but it's no excuse) Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, if you want to modify the focus transferal of the system, you should consider having a look at [Customizing Focus Traversal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal), but I'm left scratching my head as to why the OP wants to change the navigation key that ALL users would normally be use to

Comment: @MadProgrammer better now? I'm so flustered by this.

Comment: The `ActionListener` will only be triggered if the supplied input is valid - which the first part of the problem, the second is WHY does the OP want to use [Enter] to move the user to the text field

Comment: @MadProgrammer  a better choice is `tab`

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're absolutely right [Enter] is not a navigation key, but in India all accounting software employ this mechanism i.e. when you are in a form then pressing [Enter] validates field and moves to next field and people here are used to do so, and my project is also a type of accounting software. That's why...

Comment: Consider setting up your own formatter/model/validator, then you can decide when the field should lose focus - I think it comes down to the installed `InputVerifier`, but you'll have to do some digging to figure out how

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by either way.

**1.** There is a simple trick for this. After you constructed the frame with all it buttons do this:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitButton);
```

For each frame, you can set a default button that will automatically listen to the Enter key (and maybe some other event's I'm not aware of). When you hit enter in that frame, the ActionListeners their actionPerformed() method will be invoked.

**2.**  A `JFormattedTextField` was designed to use an `ActionListener` just like a JButton is. See the addActionListener() method of JFormattedTextField.

For example:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("some action");
    }
};

JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(10);
textField.addActionListener( action );
```

Now the event is fired when the `Enter` key is used.

Also, an added benefit is that you can share the listener with a button even if you don't want to make the button a default button.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Do Something");
button.addActionListener( action );
```

Note, this example uses an Action, which implements ActionListener because Action is a newer API with addition features. For example you could disable the Action which would disable the event for both the text field and the button.

Comment: I didn't know about the default. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ActionListener` you can bind `Enter` key to `JFormattedTextField` and call `AbstractAction` when `Enter` is pressed:

```
InputMap inputMap = ftf.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char) KeyEvent.VK_ENTER), "enterPressed");
        ftf.getActionMap().put("enterPressed", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("actionPerformed");
                ftfActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
```

When `JFormattedTextField` is focused it will handle `Enter` key in `actionPerformed` method